# Screensaver fine-tuning? (Gnome Linux)

Tags: linux, gnome, flash, screensaver

I'd like to know if there's any way to disable a screensaver and re-enable it automatically after I'm no longer watching the movie or tv show.

Also, can I disable the screensaver when flash (or, better, certain websites like Hulu) is on running in Firefox?

Comment: On your desktop, Totem should have a knob to enable this, if it isn't automatic.

Comment: What do you use to play videos?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at Caffeine: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/06/how-do-you-use-caffeine-the-app-not-the-stimulant/ Official Page: https://launchpad.net/caffeine